# Asp.Net static prop same domain confusing

Tags: asp.net, session, static, session-variables, static-variables

I read a answer here and he says :

> Statics are unique to the application domain, all users of that application domain will share the same value for each static property

But I am now confused I create a project for many users they will share of course the same domain.

Example Code for understanding :

```
public static class ApplicationSession
{
    private static readonly ICurrentSession Session;

    static ApplicationSession()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            Session = new ThreadedCurrentSession();
        else
        {
            Session = new WebCurrentSession();
        }
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        return (T)Session.GetItem(key);
    }

    public static void SetObject<T>(string key, T t) where T : class
    {
        Session.SetItem(key, t);
    }

}

 public static SysUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            var currentusr = ApplicationSession.GetObject<SysUser>("CurrentUser");
            if (currentusr == null)
            {
                currentusr = SysUserAccessor.CreateEmptyUser();
                currentusr.SetRoles(new List<FrUserRole>());
                ApplicationSession.SetObject("CurrentUser", currentusr);
            }
            return currentusr;
        }
    }
```

**SysUser**  is my model it drag my user and my users roles ...

Will they now share the same SysUser model if they **authenticate**.Or something else please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your ApplicationSession class is static and you initialize the Session object on its static constructor. Noto that a static constructor (or a type constructor) is called only once for whole application lifetime during first access to the type (e.g. creation its member, calling its static property, etc.). 
So, in your case, the Session variable will be initialized only once with the ThreadedCurrentSession or WebCurrentSession class (depending on if HttpContect exists when the ApplicationSession type is accessed first time).

Since the CurrentUser property is related to your Session object, it will provide the same SysUser object for all user requests.

Comment: I understand .. Do you have any Idea for  " SysUser everyone has its own ".What should I change here safely

Comment: I test it now from IIS two different browser I login with two diferent user and I can see own user profile they dont use same SysUser

Comment: I described how the demonstrated code block works. To analyze the behavior of the entire application, the entire application code should be analyzed